# Couldn't determine current channel for mon0 (Kali Linux )

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng

> aireplay-ng -0 3 -a xx:xx:xx:xx mon0 15:31:35 Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID:xx:xx:xx:xx) on channel -1 15:31:35  Couldn't determine current channel for mon0, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch
>   Please specify an ESSID (-e).

I got this error in kali linux(Latest Version with update) while using the command

```
~#aireplay-ng -0 2 -a xx:xx:xx:xx:xx mon0
```

(De-authentication attack). So, what is this error and how to resolve. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the AirPlay attack you generally need to stop the airodump process and to specify all the information required such as

```
Root@kali $: aireplay-ng -0 0 -e [target wifi mac] -a [target station mac] mon0
```

And if that doesn't work apply the '--ignore-negative-one' option

```
Root@kali $: aireplay-ng -0 0 -e [target wifi mac] -a [target station mac] --ignore-negative-one mon0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running airodump-ng currently? You need to get the channel associated first. it's a 2 part process

Ex:

airodump-ng --bssid [MAC ADDRESS] --channel 11 -w test.out mon0

aireplay-ng -1 0 -e [NameofWirelessNetwork] -a [MAC ADDRESS] -h [MAC ADDRESS] mon0

Comment: sorry about that.I miss typed. My actual command is ~#aireplay-ng -0 2 -a xx:xx:xx:xx:xx mon0. Im just stated learning this stuff and Im confusing!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you enter monitor mode you can specify a channel like this:
"airmon-ng start wlan0 x"
where x is the channel number. 
If you do not know the channel number of the AP you are educating your self on, you can start the monitor mod with an ommited chanel number, start airodump and you will see the channel number in the table. Then just restart monitor mode with that channel.